# Use dropwizard metrics with spring boot metrics

Tags: spring-boot, dropwizard, spring-micrometer

is it possible to use dropwizard metrics with spring boot 2+ metrics? Try to migrate from boot 1 to boot 2, but have some logic written based on dropwizard from boot 1, dont wanna refactor it. Want to use MetricRegistry and Clock, Histogram, etc. from dropwizard, but also have boot metrics inside it, like old one good boot 1 metrics